# Increment instance name

Tags: for-loop

Is there a way to effectively increment a instance name in, for example, a for-loop, like this?

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    City city+i = new City();
}
```

That code obviously does not work, but what can I do to create 10 objects, named City0, City1, City2 etc?

Comment: You can't do that. You can do an array of objects instead, which can hold a string field for the object name.

Comment: Please edit your question to add a language tag. Is it C++? C#? Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the cities to a list or an array and access them by index. Example of list approach in Java:

```
List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cities.add(new City());
}
```

Then, you access it like `city.get(0)` for first one `city.get(1)` for second etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
City city[10]; // declare an array of "City" objects, 10 in size

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    city[i] = new City(); //changed to an array
}
```

Comment: I'm very sorry, l just was curious, honestly. But here the assigment in the cycle is not only wrong, but the whole for is innecesary becouse your firsst line did the job completely. (ok, in the stack not the heap)

Comment: @qPCR4vir yeah thats exactly right. My guess is the teacher was trying to teach loops by doing this project with (unnecessary) loops. Since this is probably a beginners class.